# for each item add class if value is true

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, methods, vue.js

Help I'm having serious trouble I'm trying to get all the results back from a mysql query and display them. for each result `if Automotive = 1`  I would like to add a class to the paragraph tag called automotive. If `Gaming = 1` I would like to add a class called gaming. some of the results have both Automotive and Gaming set to one. in which case I would like to add both of the classes to the element. How do I do this in php? The problem I keep having is some elements are getting classes they shouldn't have. it seems like its adding the same classes for each item. Even when they don't have a value of one. Again for each result check to see if Gaming = 1 and add the Gaming class to the paragraph. If Automotive =1 add the Automotive class to the paragraph and if both classes =1 add them both and so on.  I need these classes to work so I can show and hide them conditionally in jquery/vuejs. Heres the code.

```
<?php require_once('init.php');

$query="SELECT * FROM `bannerStock`";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         $categorytoadd="";
      if($row['Automotive']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Automotive';}
                                if($row['Backgrounds']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Backgrounds';}
                                if($row['Church']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Church';}
                                if($row['Community']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Community';}
                                if($row['Money']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Money';}
                                if($row['Food']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Food';}
                                if($row['Gaming']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Gaming';}
                                if($row['Healthcare']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Healthcare';}
                                if($row['Holidays']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Holidays';}
                                if($row['Sports']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Sports';}
                                if($row['Patriotic']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Patriotic';}
                                if($row['Retail']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Retail';}
                                if($row['Education']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Education';}
                                if($row['Misc']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Misc';}
    $myArray[] = $row;
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search item'>
  <button>ALL</button>
      <button v-on:click="showgaming">Gaming</button>
      <button v-on:click="showchurch">Church</button>
      <button v-on:click="showauto">Auto</button>
      <div v-for="item in filteredItemList">
<p class="video <?php echo $categorytoadd; ?>">{{item.name_short}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      itemList: [],
        keyword:'',
        showall:'0',
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loaddata();
    },
    methods: {
            loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                        vueapp.itemList = <?php echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
                },
        showgaming: function(){
            $('.video:not(.Gaming)').hide();
        },
                showauto: function(){
            $('.video:not(.Automotive)').hide();
        },
                        showchurch: function(){
            $('.video:not(.Church)').hide();
        },
    },
        computed:{
    filteredItemList(){
      return this.itemList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name_short.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a very bad practice to mix PHP and JS code. The best way is to use an AJAX call. You can use axios with Vue to recover the values from your php. You should do your ajax call on vue's mounted or created. Then with the values recovered your v-for becomes more semantic.

Comment: I understand that I'm just testing stuff and I will use ajax after I've got it up and running. I still am having trouble dynamically adding a class depending on if the value in the database is 1 or 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Define $myArray outside the while:

```
$myArray = [];
```

2) Add the class to the row itself and push it to the array (this goes inside the while):

```
$row['class'] = $categorytoadd;
array_push($myArray, $row);
```

3) Finally, use the row class when you display the item:

```
<p :class="['video', item.class]">{{ item.name_short }}</p>
```